# How to plot zip code with lon lat to US map

Tags: latitude-longitude, shapefile, geocode

My data (305 rows) are like this:

| Zip | lon | lat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13112 | 43.10306 | -76.41926 |
| 13140 | 43.05891 | -76.65841 |
| 14456 | 42.84584 | -77.00012 |

I want to plot these coordinates as dots to a US State level map:
I am using the US state level shapefile from: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_RD18/LAYER/STATE/

The data match_zip contains the lon/lat of my points, and us_shape is my shapefile.
I am geocoding and plotting the points do not show up on map:

`coordinates(match_zip) = c("lat","lng")`
`crs.geo1 = CRS("+proj=longlat")`
`proj4string(match_zip) = crs.geo1`
`plot(us_shape)`
`points(match_zip, pch = 20, col = "orange")`